# Grails - Error Forked Grails VM exited with error

Tags: grails, manifest

First of all I would like to say that I am a beginner with Grails and while trying to follow some examples I kept getting an error I was unable to solve, so sorry if the question is stupid.

I created a dummy app through the command line, and tried to run it the same way (run-app) but I get the following error:

***Running Grails application 
Error occurred during initialization of VM Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:...\grails-2.3.1\lib\org.springsource.springloaded-core\jars\springloaded-core-1.1.4.jar agent library failed to init: instrument. 
Error Forked Grails VM exited with error***

I am using Grails 2.3.1 and jdk 1.7.0_25

I also checked the content of the folder listed on the example, and it contains the regular jar and the sources.jar as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I also had the same error, GRAILS_HOME cannot have space in path name. I remove the GRAILS_HOME, with path name and moved grails to a location without space and now it's working fine :). Here is the link I found:
http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7936

Answer (score 1):

There are currently problems with Grails 2.3.1 and 2.3.2 .

Try to insert the line below on dependencies section of the file **BuildConfig.groovy**:

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.24'
    build "org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:1.11" 
}
```

User **zyro** posted anywhere in Internet :
"this look like a incompatibility of jansi-1.2.1 with jline-2.11 on windows.

using jansi-1.11 fixed that problem for me. that was already merged into
grails-core master, too."

Comment: this just resolved my problem. Win 7 / 64bit, DK 1.7.0_45, Groovy 2.1.9, Grails 2.3.2