# Forked Grails VM exited with error

Tags: grails

I am newbie to work on the grails, I am facing problem running [odinweb](https://github.com/clulab/odinweb) project with grails, I am using grails version 2.4.4 which is required by odinweb. I also check [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545649/grails-error-forked-grails-vm-exited-with-error) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545649/grails-error-forked-grails-vm-exited-with-error), but found no luck. I am getting following runtime error.

```
Configuring classpath
| Compiling 10 source files

| Compiling 85 source files

| Packaging Grails application.....
| Running Grails application
| Enabling Tomcat NIO connector
Application context shutting down...
Application context shutdown.
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8090/odinweb
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

jdk verison 1.8.0_72

Tomcat log in **target/work/tomcat/logs/odinwe.log**

```
2016-01-29 05:56:05,556 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  conf.BootStrap  - (BootStrap.init): hostname=nlplight
2016-01-29 05:56:05,610 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Cannot invoke method getURI() on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getURI() on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:88)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:32)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at BootStrap.extractFilesFromJar(BootStrap.groovy:109)
    at BootStrap$extractFilesFromJar$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at BootStrap.copyEmbeddedDocuments(BootStrap.groovy:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1152)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:137)
    at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1081)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)
    at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:327)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:320)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:296)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.callInit(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.executeGrailsBootstraps(GrailsConfigUtils.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoaderListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It would be nice if run the application with flags --stacktrace --verbose. Something like grails run-app --stacktrace --verbose. It will give you more details about what is going on.

Comment: @FranGarcía Thanx for the reply, i tried running it through command grails -Dserver.port=8090 run-app --stacktrace --verbose, but still no logs

Answer (score 0):

It was very basic mistake in odinweb code, the object which is calling **getURI()** is getting null value as it didn't get a file at its location. I had check null condition for object and error is solved.